Optimize query by telling Postgres to scan records from the most recent to the oldest
I am using Postgres 12 and in my app I have a table that I am using to store specific events that contain information about things that happened outside of the system and related to some records in my DB.
The table looks like this:
CREATE TABLE events (
    id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    eventable_type VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    eventable_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
    type VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    data JSONB NOT NULL,
    created_at TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    updated_at TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
);
CREATE INDEX index_events_on_eventable ON events (eventable_type, eventable_id);

For example: a meeting was booked in Google calendar. An event is created in this table with the details of what happened and the record is associated with the internal representation of the meeting in the DB. The data attribute contains the details of the event that also contain a unique id like:
INSERT INTO events (eventable_type, eventable_id, type, data) VALUES ('MyInternalEvent', 1234, 'GoogleCalendarEvent', '{"action": "created", "GoogleId": "abcdef1234"}'::jsonb);
INSERT INTO events (eventable_type, eventable_id, type, data) VALUES ('MyInternalEvent', 1234, 'GoogleCalendarEvent', '{"action": "updated", "GoogleId": "abcdef1234"}'::jsonb);
INSERT INTO events (eventable_type, eventable_id, type, data) VALUES ('MyInternalEvent', 1234, 'GoogleCalendarEvent', '{"action": "deleted", "GoogleId": "abcdef1234"}'::jsonb);
INSERT INTO events (eventable_type, eventable_id, type, data) VALUES ('MyInternalEvent', 5678, 'GoogleCalendarEvent', '{"action": "created", "GoogleId": "dsfsdf2343"}'::jsonb);
INSERT INTO events (eventable_type, eventable_id, type, data) VALUES ('MyInternalEvent', 5678, 'GoogleCalendarEvent', '{"action": "updated", "GoogleId": "dsfsdf2343"}'::jsonb);
INSERT INTO events (eventable_type, eventable_id, type, data) VALUES ('MyInternalEvent', 5678, 'GoogleCalendarEvent', '{"action": "deleted", "GoogleId": "dsfsdf2343"}'::jsonb);

I query the events table like:
SELECT * FROM events WHERE events.type = 'GoogleCalendarEvent' AND (data->>'GoogleId' = 'abcdef1234') LIMIT 1;

In terms of cardinality of operations, the number of writes is approximately 3 times than the number of reads. That is: we write more than we read. The table has around 3 million rows, growing rapidly. About 300k rows are added to the table every day.
At the moment we only store one other type of event in the table, let's call it GoogleEmailEvent. Filtering by GoogleCalendarEvent would return roughly 50% of records in the table. Filtering by GoogleId would normally return less than 10 records, but we really only need 1 because they are all associated to the same "Eventable" as you can see in the example inserts.
I want to improve the execution time of the query, I have thought about:

adding an index WHERE data->>'GoogleId' IS NOT NULL. But I am worried about slowing down writes
storing data->>'GoogleId' in a separate table together with the id of the event to allow for fast retrieval. How effective would this be? This would also slow down writes somewhat.
indexing created_at and using that in the query to narrow down the records in the query somehow

Important detail:
The vast majority of the time (99% of the time or more) the matching event is one that has been inserted in the table recently (say, within 10 minutes). Can I take advantage of this details to speed up the query? Would adding ORDER BY Id DESC LIMIT 1 do the trick?

Partitioning isn't meant to improve performance in that way anyway. Indexes are. You should create an appropriate index.

What is the query?  Does it have a LIMIT?  An ORDER BY?

A complete (minimal) CREATE TABLE statement is worth more than any amount of prose beating around the bush. Plus some sample values, your indexes and the query you have now. Cardinalities and read vs. write frequency.

Good points, I have edited my question to provide the requested details! @ErwinBrandstetter jjanes

Well, better than before. But neither your CREATE TABLE statement nor your query are valid SQL. Nor is your example a valid JSON string. Provide some complete sample rows as (valid!) INSERT statement. Asking for cardinalities, I meant the number of rows in the table, how many are added per time unit, what percentage is filtered by events.type = 'GoogleCalendarEvent', how many by data #>> '{data,GoogleId}' = 'abcdef1234'. Please provide a setup that makes the question clear, and that we can readily use for tests.

Gotcha, thanks for being patient @ErwinBrandstetter, I have edited the post to provide the SQL and some example values. I ran everything with psql in a temporary PG 12 environment on my machine and everything executes correctly so it should be copy-pastable.

Your query says SELECT *, but it would seem that you only actually need SELECT eventable_id. Correct?

Yes that is correct

Basics
You can add a partial index on the expression like you already pondered:
CREATE INDEX events_special_idx ON events ((data->>'GoogleId'))
WHERE  type = 'GoogleCalendarEvent';

Query:
SELECT *
FROM   events
WHERE  type = 'GoogleCalendarEvent'
AND    data->>'GoogleId' = 'abcdef1234'
LIMIT  1;

But this is not very useful, yet. The partial index doesn't make much sense while the condition only removes half of your rows. It can be improved in many ways.
Optimize step 1
Your table is growing quickly, and so do added indexes. Your query mostly only needs recent entries. Add a cut-off timestamp to reduce the size drastically:
-- DROP INDEX CONCURRENTLY IF EXISTS events_special_idx;
CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY events_special_idx ON events ((data->>'GoogleId'))
WHERE  type = 'GoogleCalendarEvent'
AND    created_at >= '2024-08-20+0';  -- !

Add the same cut-off (or a later timestamp) to your query, so Postgres knows the index is applicable:
SELECT *
FROM   events
WHERE  type = 'GoogleCalendarEvent'
AND    data->>'GoogleId' = 'abcdef1234'
AND    created_at >= '2024-08-20+0'  -- !
LIMIT  1;

I start out with today (UTC time). The index will keep growing. You have to recreate it from time to time to keep it small. Like with a daily cron-job. I added CONCURRENTLY so as to not block writes.
Still not ideal. Postgres cannot use index-only scans with this expression, and has to introspect the (possibly big?) jsonb column every time. Plus, the expression makes writes to the index a bit more expensive, too.
Optimize step 2
The Google ID seems to be present all the time (or most of the time). A dedicated column would be much better. Actually, if your JSON document is regular, it would be much more efficient to store all plain columns instead of the JSON document to begin with. Less storage, faster access, and more. It's trivially simple and fast to add a key back to the JSON document on retrieval - or generate the whole JSON document from plain Postgres columns.
Just extracting the Google ID for a demo:
ALTER TABLE events
ADD column google_id text;

ALTER TABLE events
  ALTER column google_id TYPE text USING data->>'GoogleId'
, ALTER column data TYPE jsonb USING data - 'GoogleId'
, ALTER column google_id SET NOT NULL;

The ALTER TABLE "trick" is the fastest way to rewrite the whole table, but it blocks concurrent writes. (I would really recreate the whole table with additional optimizations.)
Now, the index can be:
CREATE INDEX events_special2_idx ON events (google_id) INCLUDE (eventable_id)
WHERE  type = 'GoogleCalendarEvent'
AND    created_at >= '2024-08-20+0';

Assuming you only need eventable_id, I added that with an INCLUDE clause to make it a covering index. Now, if the table is vacuum'ed enough, you get index-only scans:
SELECT eventable_id
FROM   events
WHERE  type = 'GoogleCalendarEvent'
AND    google_id = 'abcdef1234'
AND    created_at >= '2024-08-20+0'
LIMIT  1;

fiddle
Storing the lengthy strings 'GoogleCalendarEvent' / 'GoogleEmailEvent' as type over and over is wasteful. I would replace that with something more efficient. Etc.
Data types and the table layout might be optimized some more, too. See:

Calculating and saving space in PostgreSQL


Would it make sense to create a partial index WHERE data->>'GoogleId' IS NOT NULL like I mentioned in my question? As mentioned, there are normally about 10 records or so with a certain GoogleId. From what you said I am guessing the drawback is that the index would be very big.

@Perennialista: You'd rather use WHERE data ? 'GoogleId'. Either way, only selective filters are beneficial for a partial index.

Thank you @Erwin Brandstetter! I was collecting some data to see how the application performed and I can confirm creating an index on data->>'GoogleId' did make a massive difference on the performance! I still have to implement some of the other suggestions but will report back when I do.
